# Optimising a for loop for adding elements in an arraylist

Tags: java

I have a loop in which n is very large. I have an arraylist alist which goes on adding elements one by one after each subsequent run of loop. Is there any method of optimising this loop so that code runs faster or any other method to add elements parallely.
Thanks in advance.

```
                for(int i=0;i<=n;i++)
                {
                  / *
                   some code
                  */
                   alist.add(element);
                }
```

Comment: Given your problem statement and use of "some code" I would say the answer is "how long is a piece of string".

Answer (score 2):

When you instantiate the array list, make sure you use the single argument constructor:

`ArrayList</*your type*/>(n + 1)`

This will set the *capacity* of the `ArrayList` to the required number of elements. Doing so prevents memory reallocations which will help runtime performance. It doesn't *restrict* the `ArrayList` capacity but advises the object that it could get that big.

As for further optimisations, that would really depend on whether or not `/*some code*/` is the bottleneck; which it probably is.

Answer (score 2):

Actually doing it *in parallel* (on multiple threads) would likely be *slower* as they'd all be in contention, since you have to serialize access to the `ArrayList`.

About the only thing you can realistically do (based on what little information is in the question) is ensure that the `ArrayList` has enough *capacity* at the outset for all of the elements you're going to add, so it doesn't have to do a bunch of reallocations as you go. Assuming you already have an `alist`, you do this by calling [`ensureCapacity`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#ensureCapacity-int-):

```
alist.ensureCapacity(alist.size() + n + 1); // +1 because you're adding n+1 elements
for (int i = 0; i <= n; i++) {              // Note this loops n+1 times
    alist.add(/*...some element...*/);
}
```

If you *don't* already have `alist`, you do it by giving an argument to the constructor:

```
alist = new ArrayList(n + 1);
for (int i = 0; i <= n; i++) {
```

If you don't do that, the `ArrayList` may have to reallocate the array repeatedly during the loop, which is slower than doing it once at the outset.

If you already have a collection of some kind and are adding all elements from that collection to `alist`, rather than doing it yourself, you can use `addAll`. But that basically just does `ensureCapacity` followed by a bunch of `adds`.

Comment: I confess I stole your `n + 1`. Please accept my apologies in the form of an upvote.

Comment: @Bathsheba: LOL :-) And +1 to your answer as well (lots of +1s around here).

Answer (score 1):

If you are using an `ArrayList` then presumably order is important. In that case you really can't use conventional techniques to add elements in different threads. They will still end up having to be processed in serial to be added in correct order.

Depending on your application it may be possible to use Java 8 threads. If each of the elements can be processed in parallel then it might be possible to perform each of the steps independently and then collect the results into a list. Something like:

```
List<Element> result = IntStream.range(0, n).parallel()
    .mapToObj(n -> codeCreatingElement(n)).collect(Collectors.toList());
```